# I need some fix with the CSS hover effect

Tags: css, hover

I am doing some custom CSS & I am trying to create sub-categories to show when mouse hovers on the Icon & the Heading.

I was able to achieve the hover effect when you mouse over the icon but have spent two days but no luck with the heading.

[Please see this screenshot for easy understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNP7P.jpg)

Here's the code

```
/*this doesnt work*/
.cnt-box-side-icon > .caption h2:hover + .caption p {
      display: block;

}

/*this works*/
.cnt-box-side-icon i:hover + .caption p {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.caption p 
{
    display:none;
  animation: fadein 1s;

}
```

Thanks in Advance!
Ashish

Comment: can you shate html too?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, I can see in the inspector that the `h2` and `p` elements are siblings. Your selector should be:

```
.cnt-box-side-icon > .caption h2:hover + p
```

Browsers read selectors from right to left. This selector reads as:

> a `p` element
> that is an adjacent sibling of an `h2` element with a `hover` pseudo-class
> that is a descendent of a `caption` class
> that is a direct child of a `cnt-box-side-icon` class

Read more: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (MDN)

Comment: Thanks charles! worked like a charm. Also very nicely explained :)